# How to use the pseudo selectors in Inline Css in material UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Below code works for me when added to index.css in react project.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

I want to this in inline css.
How can I use this code as inline css for material UI Textfield components using sx or styled component. Any sample code could be helpfull. Thank you

Comment: Inline styles cannot be used to style pseudo-classes.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it using styled component?

Comment: If your styled component tool creates CSS rules (as opposed to rules directly on element "style" attributes), then it may be possible.

Comment: Could provide the sample code

Comment: I don't know how your styled components work.